# Implementation of algorithm to enumerate all vertices of a convex polyhedron defined as linear inequalities?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I am looking for an implementation for any of the methods to enumerate all vertices of a convex polyhedron defined by $Ax \leq b$

I have found some papers that talk about the problem, for example [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0925772195000496) seems like a good lead. However, it is described at a very abstract level, to facilitate proving correctness, ease of implementation and testing is more challenging.

Another lead I have is the Double Description method, but that one seems challenging to implement and I do need to implement whatever algorithm I choose from scratch.